# Number of Android Wear that can be paired to Android Phone

Tags: android, android-emulator, wear-os

Started working on Android Wear, I could able to pair my Phone with Emulator. I am thinking to buy a device, So my question is ,

Is it possible that a Single Wear can Pair with multiple android devices and Vice versa ? I mean 2 to 3 wear devices with single android device.

Answer (score 3):

**Nope, you can't pair a single wear with multiple android devices at a time.**

Even if a wear is already connected with a phone/tablet and if you would want to switch device then you will have to reset the wear.

Read more on [Different ways to pair your watch](https://support.google.com/androidwear/answer/6058799?hl=en).